# Massive parallel computation ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a method that performs a mathematical  operation repeatedly (possibly millions on times) with different data. What is the best way to do this in iOs (it will run on iPad devices)?  I understand that `performSelectorOnBackgroundThread` is deprecated... ? I also need to aggregate all the results in an `NSArray` . The best way seems to be: post a notification to the Notification Center and add the method as an observer. Is this correct? The array will need to be declared as atomic, I believe... Plus I will need to show a progress bar as the operations complete... How many threa can I start in parallel ? I don't think starting 1.000.000 threads is such a good idea on an iDevice..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't like to have an IFrontEnd to an (no-i)major computer with massively parallel, vectored capabilities?

Comment: Have you already tested out the naive approach (running it just sequentially on the main thread) and tested to see how long that takes (if so, how long)? Do any of the computations depend on the results of the other computations?

Comment: So far all testing was done on the simulator ... which is much faster ... the computations do not depend on any of the results of all the other computations ... they are independent

Answer (score 4):

Look into [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch), it's the preferred way to do multi-threading on iOS (and Mac).

A simple example of using GCD would look like:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //do long running task here
}
```

This will execute a block asynchronously of the main thread. GCD has numerous other ways of dispatching tasks, one taken directly from the Wikipedia article listed above is:

```
dispatch_apply(count, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(size_t i){
     results[i] = do_work(data, i);
    });
total = summarize(results, count);
```

This particular code sample is probably exactly what you're looking for, assuming this "large task" of yours is a [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).

Comment: it is embarrassingly parallel ... (it's a monte carlo algo )

Answer (score 3):

While you could use `dispatch_apply()` and spin off all of the runs simultaneously, that'll end up being slower.

You'll want to be able to throttle the # of runs in flight simultaneously with the # of simultaneous computations being something that you'll need to tune.

I've often used a `dispatch_semaphore_t` to allow for easy tuning of the # of in-flight computations.

Details of doing so are in an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535110/25646