# Why am I getting 620 errors when I multithread [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:someURL];?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

Here is a snippet of code I am using.
I have a model called `x_locator`. When I multithread the model, maps.google.com returns 620 errors (too many requests too fast), but when I leave the model on the main thread it works fine... only the UI is locked up while the requests are being made.

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?    q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double lat = 0.0;
    double lon = 0.0;

    if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        lat = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        lon = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Address, %@ not found: Error %@",addressStr, [items objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = lat;
    location.longitude = lon;

    return location;
}
```

EDIT: Here is how I attempted to use GCD... this is in my ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set any delegates
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    fuelMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self setInitialRegion];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;

    //create the model
    x_locator = [[Locator alloc]init];
    x_locator.delegate = self;

    dispatch_queue_t finder = dispatch_queue_create("Locator", NULL);
    //if I do this, only some of the locations are found. If I leave it on the main thread, all locations are found.
    dispatch_async(finder, ^{
    [x_locator getUsersZipUsingLocation:[locationManager location]];
     });
}
```

All `getUsersZipUsingLocation:` does is get the users zip code using reverse geocoding and then it calls another method which retrieves an array of addresses (according to the users zip), and finally each of those addresses is converted into a coordinate location using `-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr`

EDIT 2: 
I'm very hesitant to post the code in it's entirety due to the possibility of people losing focus of the question and proceeding to judge the elegance of my coding....

Anyway...before I call the method `-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr`, I have to assemble the addresses into a form that I can pass as the variable `addressStr`. The address arrives in pieces so I assemble the pieces then proceed to get the data from the url...

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",
                    [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

After the data is returned, I say `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];` and the next request is taken.

I appreciate your comments and time :)

Comment: How are you multithreading it? GCD, NSThread...? Please share the code that you are using, I'd guess you are creating multiple threads that all execute this simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah I'm using GCD (hence the tag). I'm about to post some more code to show how I'm multithreading.

Comment: missed the tag, sorry... that's what I get for posting on my phone :)

Answer (score 2):

First, `getLocationFromAddressString:` should not be prefixed with `get`;  try `download` or `retrieve` or just omit it (convention).

Secondly, post details on how you are actually making the call concurrent.  How many requests are you making?

"Too many requests too fast" sounds pretty darned precise;  you need to throttle the speed at which you toss requests at the remote server.

I've used semaphores to throttle concurrency in the past.

[Grand Central Strategy for Opening Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532509/grand-central-strategy-for-opening-multiple-files)

---

> All getUsersZipUsingLocation: does is get the users zip code using
>   reverse geocoding and then it calls another method which retrieves an
>   array of addresses (according to the users zip), and finally each of
>   those addresses is converted into a coordinate location using
>   -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr

Where it is called via:

```
dispatch_async(finder, ^{
[x_locator getUsersZipUsingLocation:[locationManager location]];
 });
```

First, you now have an asynchronous call to load that information.   Thus, no surprise that "only some" of the items are found.  As soon as you move to asynchronous, you *must use some kind of a notification mechanism to indicate when the load is done*.

Assuming that `usersZipUsingLocation:` is synchronous, you could:

```
dispatch_async(finder, ^{
[x_locator getUsersZipUsingLocation:[locationManager location]];
[self yoManILoadedTheGoodsDealWithTheUpdate];
 });
```

But that still doesn't explain your 620.  That 620 would indicate that you are firing off a bunch of requests simultaneously (or nearly so).  Nor does any of the above have the claimed 50msec delay.

So... there appears to be more to this story! :)

---

Still not clear why you are hitting the API request limit.

You really shouldn't use a sleep mechanism for delaying these kinds of things.  Instead, use a combination of a semaphore like pattern to control the # of simultaneous in flight requests (preferably using the asynchronous loading API of the system) combined with a timer based delay, if absolutely necessary.   That pushes all the delay related stuff off to the system without a guaranteed thread contract (as required by sleeping a thread).

Comment: Yeah I need to rename a bunch of stuff...
But yeah, I'm making each request 50 milliseconds apart and this has been working fine when it's on the main thread (but like I said the UI is locked up).

For some reason, when I multithread, it acts as if the 50ms delay isn't there...

Comment: **How are you achieving concurrency?**   Until you answer that, not much more anyone might suggest.  As it is, "50ms apart on the main thread" implies zero concurrency and "I'm using GCD" implies that you might be firing off all requests simultaneously.